# Stack Exchange login change to a different email id

Tags: discussion, login, email

I have shifted my email from a Gmail account to one hosted by myself (thanks to Snowden leaks).

However, since I was earlier using my Gmail account to login, I still have to give the same old address to login but for all other purposes I have changed my email address to my new one. Is there any way I can change the login username also?

Answer (score 6):

At the top of any Stack Exchange site, click on your profile:

[image]

Next click on *Edit Profile & Settings* and do whatever you need to do:

[image]

Then click *My Logins*:

[image]

Comment: -1: No freehand circles

Comment: I'm logged in by my gmail account, now I want to change my email to another gmail id but once after clicking on gmail option for new login, the page gets refresh as I'm already logged in from a gmail id. any solution?

Comment: I don't get it. I'd like to change my login id to my current email address. I can't remove my current login as it's my only login (what with JanRain gone.) Do I have to add an AOL login to change my email login?

Comment: OK, I tried that. Now, I can _only_ log in with my AOL OpenID. Ah... that's suboptimal. How can I add a username and password back to my account?