# How can I add a new email login to my profile? Why is GitHub only available as login option on SO, but not network sites?

Tags: support, login, network-sites

I originally created this account as login with Google. Recently (a few months ago) I added my GitHub login to this account, and removed my Google account. I remained logged into all of my network sites, but once I logged out, and back in to SO, I was no longer logged into any of my network profiles as they don't have GitHub as a login option.

I was able to regain access to my network sites by going through the "forgot password" option, and giving the email address associated with my original Google account. The email I received said that my email address was associated with a Stack Exchange account, but no password was set, and the link allowed me to add a password, and now I can log into my account on other network sites.

However this is still unsatisfying for me personally, as I would like to have a login that does not use this Gmail address, as I no longer use that email address.

Is it possible to add a new email-password login to my existing account? I can't seem to find out how to do so.

EDIT: to those marking this as duplicate, none of those posts have a satisfactory answer. I know how to add logins in the settings, but that page only allows you to add SSO logins, and I don't see the option to add an email and password login.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack Exchange login change to a different email id](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269758/stack-exchange-login-change-to-a-different-email-id)

Comment: Maybe relevant: [Change login email for Stack Exchange (stackoverflow.com)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373582/11682469)

Comment: MSE FAQ: [How do I change my login provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793)

Comment: @JeanneDark thank you! the answer to that second link helps :) feels awfully hacky though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! This is a bit unintuitive, but if you are having this problem, you need to add a new email address to your account, and remove the old one.

At this point you can't log in with your old password, because it is tied to the original email address.

If you then do the forgot password with the new email address, you will get a link to generate a password for it.